# Maximum number of distinct substrings

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics

## Description

Given a length `n`, and an alphabet size `k>0`, your program must determine the number of strings with those parameters which have a maximal number of unique substrings. In the case of `k=2`, this generates OEIS [A134457](https://oeis.org/A134457).

## Example

For example, `2210` has the substrings   , `2`, `22`, `221`, `2210`, `2`, `21`, `210`, `1`, `10`, and `0`, for a total of 11. However, `2` appears twice, so it only has 10 unique substrings.

This is as many as possible for a length 4 string containing 3 different symbols, but it ties with 35 other strings for a total of 36 tieing strings including `0012`, `2101`, and `0121`. Therefore, for `n=4` and `k=3`, your program should output 36.

## Test Cases

```
n    k    output

0    5    1
1    3    3
5    1    1
9    2    40
2    3    6
5    5    120
```

Comment: Could you please give some examples? It's kind of hard to follow the challenge from that very short description.

Comment: So wouldn't `n=2`, `k=3` output 9: `11,12,21,22,31,32,33,13,23`?

Comment: @veganaiZe The double digits have a repeated substring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
ṗµẆQLµ€ML
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9qZWxsef//4bmXwrXhuoZRTMK14oKsTUz///8y/zk)

Input in reversed order. Brute force.

Comment: Save a byte by avoiding the three-atom chain with a transpose and tail: `ṗẆQ$€ZṪL`

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 12 bytes

```
l.Ml{.:Z)^UE
```

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=l.Ml%7B.%3AZ%29%5EUE&input=9%0A2&debug=0)

Pure brute force.

#### Explanation

- Implicit: append `Q` to the program.
- Implicit: read and evaluate a line of input (`n`) in `Q`.
- `E`: read and evaluate a line of input (`k`).
- `U`: get a range `[0, ..., k-1]`.
- `^`: get all `n`-length strings of `[0, ..., k-1]`.
- `.M`: find the ones that give a maximum for function `f(Z)`:

  - `.:Z`: find the substrings of `Z`
  - `{`: remove duplicates
  - `l`: get the number of unique substrings
- `l`: get the number of such strings

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 96 bytes

```
Last[Last/@Tally[Length@Union@Flatten[Table[Partition[#,i,1],{i,s}],1]&/@Tuples[Range@#2,s=#]]]&
```

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 82 bytes

```
import Data.Lists
l=length
n#k=l$argmaxes(l.nub.powerslice)$mapM id$[1..k]<$[1..n]
```

Usage example: `9 # 2` -> `40`.

How it works:

```
       [1..k]<$[1..n]  --  make a list of n copies of the list [1..k]
      mapM id          --  make a list of all combinations thereof, where
                       --  the 1st element is from the f1st list, 2nd from 2nd etc
  argmaxes             --  find all elements which give the maximum value for function:
     l.nub.powerslice  --    length of the list of unique sublists
l                      --  take the length of this list
```